# mySQL LOAD DATA INFILE missing every second row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import postcode data into a single table in my db, and for some reason the LOAD DATA INFILE query is only loading every second row of data, which has me somewhat puzzled.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$data' INTO TABLE postcode_data 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' 
    IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Where `$data` is the path to one of *many* files of postcode data (when you get them from the ONS they come batched per postcode area).

Example data:

```
pcd,pcd2,pcds,dointr,doterm,oscty,ced,oslaua,osward,parish,usertype,oseast1m,osnrth1m,osgrdind,oshlthau,nhser,ctry,rgn,streg,pcon,eer,teclec,ttwa,pct,nuts,statsward,oa01,casward,park,lsoa01,msoa01,ur01ind,oac01,oa11,lsoa11,msoa11,wz11,ccg,bua11,buasd11,ru11ind,oac11,lat,long,lep1,lep2,pfa,imd,calncv,stp
"AB1 0AA","AB1  0AA","AB1 0AA","198001","199606","S99999999","S99999999","S12000033","S13002843","S99999999","0","385386","0801193","1","S08000020","S99999999","S92000003","S99999999","0","S14000002","S15000001","S09000001","S22000047","S03000012","S31000935","99ZZ00","S00001364","01C30","S99999999","S01000011","S02000007","6","3C2","S00090303","S01006514","S02001237","S34002990","S03000012","S99999999","S99999999","3","1C3",57.101474,-2.242851,"S99999999","S99999999","S23000009",6808,"S99999999","S99999999"
"AB1 0AB","AB1  0AB","AB1 0AB","198001","199606","S99999999","S99999999","S12000033","S13002843","S99999999","0","385177","0801314","1","S08000020","S99999999","S92000003","S99999999","0","S14000002","S15000001","S09000001","S22000047","S03000012","S31000935","99ZZ00","S00001270","01C31","S99999999","S01000011","S02000007","6","4B3","S00090303","S01006514","S02001237","S34002990","S03000012","S99999999","S99999999","3","1C3",57.102554,-2.246308,"S99999999","S99999999","S23000009",6808,"S99999999","S99999999"
"AB1 0AD","AB1  0AD","AB1 0AD","198001","199606","S99999999","S99999999","S12000033","S13002843","S99999999","0","385053","0801092","1","S08000020","S99999999","S92000003","S99999999","0","S14000002","S15000001","S09000001","S22000047","S03000012","S31000935","99ZZ00","S00001364","01C30","S99999999","S01000011","S02000007","6","3C2","S00090399","S01006514","S02001237","S34003015","S03000012","S99999999","S99999999","3","6A1",57.100556,-2.248342,"S99999999","S99999999","S23000009",6808,"S99999999","S99999999"
"AB1 0AE","AB1  0AE","AB1 0AE","199402","199606","S99999999","S99999999","S12000034","S13002864","S99999999","0","384600","0799300","8","S08000020","S99999999","S92000003","S99999999","0","S14000058","S15000001","S09000001","S22000047","S03000013","S31001005","99ZZ00","S00002142","02C58","S99999999","S01000333","S02000061","6","3B1","S00091322","S01006853","S02001296","S34003292","S03000013","S99999999","S99999999","6","1A2",57.084444,-2.255708,"S99999999","S99999999","S23000009",5503,"S99999999","S99999999"
"AB1 0AF","AB1  0AF","AB1 0AF","199012","199207","S99999999","S99999999","S12000033","S13002843","S99999999","1","384460","0800660","8","S08000020","S99999999","S92000003","S99999999","0","S14000002","S15000001","S09000001","S22000047","S03000012","S31000934","99ZZ00","S00001266","01C30","S99999999","S01000007","S02000003","3","4D2","S00090299","S01006511","S02001236","S34003015","S03000012","S99999999","S99999999","3","6A4",57.096656,-2.258102,"S99999999","S99999999","S23000009",6668,"S99999999","S99999999"
```

My code loops over every individual file and 'successfully' imports the data. But missing every second row.

If I remove the `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED` line, then I get every row but with imported quotes, which is also a bit useless.

Failed import (19397 lines imported):

```
AB1 0AA AB1  0AA    AB1 0AA 198001  199606  S999999 S999999 S120000 S130028 S999999 0   385386  0801193 1   S080000 S999999 S920000 S999999 0   S140000 S150000 S090000 S220000 S030000 S310009 99ZZ00  S000013 01C30   S999999 S010000 S020000 6   3C2 S000903 S010065 S020012 S340029 S030000 S999999 S999999 3   1C3 57.1014 -2.2428 S999999 S999999 S230000 6808    S999999 S999999
AB1 0AD AB1  0AD    AB1 0AD 198001  199606  S999999 S999999 S120000 S130028 S999999 0   385053  0801092 1   S080000 S999999 S920000 S999999 0   S140000 S150000 S090000 S220000 S030000 S310009 99ZZ00  S000013 01C30   S999999 S010000 S020000 6   3C2 S000903 S010065 S020012 S340030 S030000 S999999 S999999 3   6A1 57.1005 -2.2483 S999999 S999999 S230000 6808    S999999 S999999
AB1 0AF AB1  0AF    AB1 0AF 199012  199207  S999999 S999999 S120000 S130028 S999999 1   384460  0800660 8   S080000 S999999 S920000 S999999 0   S140000 S150000 S090000 S220000 S030000 S310009 99ZZ00  S000012 01C30   S999999 S010000 S020000 3   4D2 S000902 S010065 S020012 S340030 S030000 S999999 S999999 3   6A4 57.0966 -2.2581 S999999 S999999 S230000 6668    S999999 S999999
```

With removed `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY` clause (38794 lines imported):

```
"AB1 0AA    "AB1  0A    "AB1 0AA    "198001 "199606 "S99999 "S99999 "S12000 "S13002 "S99999 "0" "385386 "080119 "1" "S08000 "S99999 "S92000 "S99999 "0" "S14000 "S15000 "S09000 "S22000 "S03000 "S31000 "99ZZ00 "S00001 "01C30" "S99999 "S01000 "S02000 "6" "3C2"   "S00090 "S01006 "S02001 "S34002 "S03000 "S99999 "S99999 "3" "1C3"   57.1014 -2.2428 "S99999 "S99999 "S23000 6808    "S99999 "S99999
"AB1 0AB    "AB1  0A    "AB1 0AB    "198001 "199606 "S99999 "S99999 "S12000 "S13002 "S99999 "0" "385177 "080131 "1" "S08000 "S99999 "S92000 "S99999 "0" "S14000 "S15000 "S09000 "S22000 "S03000 "S31000 "99ZZ00 "S00001 "01C31" "S99999 "S01000 "S02000 "6" "4B3"   "S00090 "S01006 "S02001 "S34002 "S03000 "S99999 "S99999 "3" "1C3"   57.1025 -2.2463 "S99999 "S99999 "S23000 6808    "S99999 "S99999
"AB1 0AD    "AB1  0A    "AB1 0AD    "198001 "199606 "S99999 "S99999 "S12000 "S13002 "S99999 "0" "385053 "080109 "1" "S08000 "S99999 "S92000 "S99999 "0" "S14000 "S15000 "S09000 "S22000 "S03000 "S31000 "99ZZ00 "S00001 "01C30" "S99999 "S01000 "S02000 "6" "3C2"   "S00090 "S01006 "S02001 "S34003 "S03000 "S99999 "S99999 "3" "6A1"   57.1005 -2.2483 "S99999 "S99999 "S23000 6808    "S99999 "S99999
"AB1 0AE    "AB1  0A    "AB1 0AE    "199402 "199606 "S99999 "S99999 "S12000 "S13002 "S99999 "0" "384600 "079930 "8" "S08000 "S99999 "S92000 "S99999 "0" "S14000 "S15000 "S09000 "S22000 "S03000 "S31001 "99ZZ00 "S00002 "02C58" "S99999 "S01000 "S02000 "6" "3B1"   "S00091 "S01006 "S02001 "S34003 "S03000 "S99999 "S99999 "6" "1A2"   57.0844 -2.2557 "S99999 "S99999 "S23000 5503    "S99999 "S99999
"AB1 0AF    "AB1  0A    "AB1 0AF    "199012 "199207 "S99999 "S99999 "S12000 "S13002 "S99999 "1" "384460 "080066 "8" "S08000 "S99999 "S92000 "S99999 "0" "S14000 "S15000 "S09000 "S22000 "S03000 "S31000 "99ZZ00 "S00001 "01C30" "S99999 "S01000 "S02000 "3" "4D2"   "S00090 "S01006 "S02001 "S34003 "S03000 "S99999 "S99999 "3" "6A4"   57.0966 -2.2581 "S99999 "S99999 "S23000 6668    "S99999 "S99999
```

Can anyone suggest what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

As always, the answer is found in the last place you look....

This was annoyingly trivial after spending a few hours on it. The problem was the line terminators should have been \r\n, not just \n. Doh. Hope this helps someone else out in future.